# "I'll see that the problem <is> <will be> dealt with."

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-tense, future-constructions

[thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deal):
**(1)** *I'll see that the problem **is** dealt with*.
my variant:
**(2)** *I'll see that the problem **will be** dealt with*.

To me, (1) is wrong because, as far as I understand its meaning, dealing with the problem will be happening in the future, so we must use (2).
Why is (1) correct?
What's the difference between (1) and (2)?

An update:
Maybe the that-clause in (1) is in the covert subjunctive. Is it so?
If so, we can rewrite it using a usual subjunctive form:
**(3)** *I'll see that the problem **be** dealt with*.
Is (3) correct?

Comment: It is idiom. Similarly "I will make sure you catch the train." The action is "catch the train" and in the question the action is "dealt with". There is no subjunctive in the statement.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is (2) correct? Does it mean the same as (1)? Thanks.

Comment: Example 2 means the same but is not idiomatic. You already use the future tense in "I'll see" so then it is a statement about what will be in the future. Alternatively, just "The problem will be dealt with".

Comment: @WeatherVane Will (1) be idiomatic if we rewrite it the following way?:  "_I'll see that the problem has been dealt with_." Thanks.

Comment: thefreedictionary.com has already advised you of the idiomatic use. Go with it. Sometimes it is difficult to explain exactly why English learners' inventions are incorrect. My eyes/ears tell me so. I don't even get why you ask "Can I say say this?" when you already read in a dictionary how to say it.

Comment: You say *dealing with the problem will be happening in the future, so we must use (2)* - but this is something very subtle and specific to English.    From the perspective of *now*, it is in the future, so you say "I *will* make sure", but in the future, "dealing with it" is simply a current fact, not "in the future" any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first sentence is correct.

Even though it refers to an event in the future, when "see that" has the function of "ensure that", the structure is: *[ "see (to it) that" + clause with **present tense** ]*

It can be any present tense:

> I'll see (to it) that she **leaves** the party by 9 pm.
> I'll see (to it) that she **is heading** home by 9 pm.
> I'll see (to it) that she **has left** the party by 9 pm.